# SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to Class extending from SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

In my activity I have want to use a `GoogleMap` in a `NestedScrollView` for this I have created a `Class : MySupportMapFragment` so that my touch events work well for the map inside NestedScrollView.
But My application crashes when I cast `SupportMapFragment` to `MySupportMapFragment`.

**Code:**
*MySupportMapFragment:*

```
    public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

        private OnTouchListener mListener;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

            TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            return layout;
        }

        public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public interface OnTouchListener {
            public abstract void onTouch();
        }

        public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

            public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mListener.onTouch();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mListener.onTouch();
                        break;
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }


inside Activity extending from `AppCompatActivity` 

MySupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        mapFragment = (MySupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(mapFragment != null)
            mapFragment.setListener(new MySupportMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTouch() {
                    nv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            });

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

**xml:**

```
<root>
.....
....

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/map"
                            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

                            />

....
</root>
```

Comment: try to change value of  android:name in xml to package.name.MySupportMapFragment

Comment: ok lemme check.

Comment: thanks you saved my day :)